# How may I start a process without having network access and later allow network access?

Tags: linux, networking

I want to run a process without network access but at a later time give access to the network.

The computer will have full network connection as all the other processes but I want to start just one process without network access. (I have already checked this process runs fine without networking)

Comment: Can tell us a bit more about what you mean?  Are you saying the computer will not be on the network at startup, but will become available later?

Comment: depends intirely on the process / software.  Some software wont boot unless network connectivity is established.

Comment: Your edit didn't help.

Comment: Sounds more like you are asking us for permission. In that case, yeah, go ahead! If your question is more technical, please expand the description of your problem (if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iptables with the owner match should work.

`iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --cmd-owner "/usr/local/bin/app" -j DROP`

There's also a --pid-owner if your kernel doesn't support cmd-owner or you really mean one process as opposed to any process of an app. --uid-owner may also meet your needs.